# Add and remove active class on item click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a menu using bootstrap that has a class ".active" for the first menu item. But I want  to remove this ".active" class when other item is clicked and add the active classs to that clicked item. Also if a sub menu item is clicked i want to add the ".active" class just to the main list item not to the sub item clicked.

I have the code below for this but its not working properly. Do you know how to fix?

**html**

```
<nav id="nav">
    <ul class="">
        <li class="active"><a href="url">Item 0</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#edit" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
               Item 1
            </a>
            <ul class="collapse" id="edit">
                <li><a href="/create">Create</a></li>
                <li><a href="/edit">Edit</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/posts">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/categories">Item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**js**

```
 $("#nav li").on("click", function() {
        $(".nav li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are removing class instead of an id:

`$(".nav li").removeClass("active");`

instead of:

`$("#nav li").removeClass("active");`

UPDATE:

To ensure that the children `li`s don't get the class, you can do this:

```js
$("#nav li").on("click", function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     if ($(this).parent().hasClass('collapse')) {
        $(this).parent().parent().addClass("active");
     } else {
       $("#nav li").removeClass("active");
       $(this).addClass("active");
     }
});
```

Of course, you can re-write your html to make jQuery selectors less cumbersome.

Comment: Thanks, but its not working properly. When the menu item is clicked the background color changes to white because of the .active class is applied. But the white background color then change to the previous color and the first menu item becomes again with the background color white because of the .active class.

Comment: That confuses me - can you put that in a fiddle or something? It is not clear what you are looking for.

Comment: For example, the first item has the active class, but then when the "Item 2" for example is clicked i want to remove the .active class from the first list item and give the active class to the clicked item to inform that the user is in that menu item. But for this to work maybe its necessary something with the urls, so maybe its not possible to put in a fiddle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4a2oxL92/ Notice how the active class gets applied to parents of sub menus not the sub menu `li`s. Links shouldn't matter when replicating the problem. Just add the `e.preventDefault();` as I did in the fiddle. As you've explained it, the fiddle does exactly that.